# display image from file on server using mysql query

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to get my image file to load. It keeps showing the broken file icon and a box where the image should be but no image from the file path I designated. My $row['pic'] should output "profile/test5.jpg" from my MYSQL database which together with the "http://localhost/system/" should make it a valid source. When I inspect the HTML page it says source unknown. Please help I really need this to show dynamic images on my webpage. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","system");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];
if($action=="showroom"){
$query="SELECT * FROM id WHERE name='Tom Smith'";
$show=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Error");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($show)){
echo "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
$location = 'http://localhost/system/' . $row['pic'];
echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "' . $location .'"/>';
}
}
?>
```

In case it is relevant here is the other piece of AJAX I am using.

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function showRoom(){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"process.php",
data:{action:"showroom"},
success:function(data){
$("#content").html(data);
}
});
}
showRoom();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to see if you can get `http://localhost/system/profile/test5.jpg` shown as expected?

Comment: Thank you. I will try that when I get home. I think I have tried that before and it displays properly. My trouble is I need it to display based on $row['pic'] again thank you. If you have any other ideas please lmk.

Comment: Yes that worked. However it does not solve my problem. Any ideas as to why the $row['pic'] is not translating into http://localhost/system/profile/test5.jpg ?

Comment: My suggestions: 1 load `/path-to-this/process.php?action=showroom` to see what you get. 2. Use the developer tool of your browser to check the element source code of the section where you get the `the broken file icon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code. Just check in the browser console, is there any error, most probably it will be of jQuery, due to network error (In this case try making the `jquery.js` file offline and use that rather than using CDN). If this is fine, check the output of the server in browser's network tab for `process.php` output or Inspect element feature of the browser to check whether there is the image element with

```
<img src="localhost/system/profile/test5.jpg" />
```

If this is fine, the image will be ofcourse visible as you have also verified that when you directly hit the url `localhost/system/profile/test5.jpg`, you can see the image.

If the `img` element do not have any `src` value or broken value (`localhost/system` only), it means the query you run

```
select * from id where name = 'Tom Smith'
```

did not returned any result. If this query returned result you will see the `Name` and `Image` below that.

Hopefully this way you will be able to debug your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution to my problem.

Comment: Welcome!! Glad to know it helped!!